# file_exists doesn't find image with Cyrillic name

Tags: php, filenames, file-exists

I have this image "Трислоен-паркет.png" and this to check if it exists:

```
$imgs='../images/pc/'.clear_string($categoryrow[1],$tr).'.png';        
if(file_exists($imgs)){ echo 'yes';
}else echo 'no';
```

It always returns NO.
The strange thing is that if I call the image without check if it is exists - it shows the image but I need to DO check and show that image if exists, otherwise I will show default image..but file_exists does wrong ..

clear_string function only removes white spaces and commas and some other type letters..
how to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) to set the language format you pass to the functions such as file_exists.

Your code might look something like this:

```
file_exists(iconv('iso-8859-5', 'utf-8', $imgs));
```

Comment: no, that did not solve the problem too.. I tried different version of encoding for iconv..

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that file_exists checks starting from root and in this case the path was wrong.. no encoding was needed.. Sorry guys for taking your time and thanks for your answers !..